# Java - Why code with just {} works and is parsed by virtual machine?

Tags: java

I found something like this and I have a question why this works and how JVM parses it?

```
class app {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public void foo() {
        System.out.print("Hello World");
    }

    {
        foo();
    }
}
```

Of course, there's not showing message (because `foo()` is not in main function), but I'm thinking why code in just {} are not throwing an error.

Here's in online compiler: http://goo.gl/TLv3JH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, your example is known as an **instance initializer**. It will be run every time a new object `app` is called.

It can be useful for different reasons. As an example:

```
public class App{

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        new App();
        new App();
    }

    static{
        System.out.println( "static initializer" );
    }

    public App(){
        System.out.println( "constructor" );
    }

    {
        System.out.println( "instance initializer" );
    }
}
```

Will output:

```
static initializer
instance initializer
constructor
instance initializer
constructor
```

So, a `static initializer` runs once when the class if first loaded, before anything else. An `instance initializer` runs at each instantiation **before the constructor.**

Answer (score 4):

What you have is an instance initializer. The code in this block is executed every time you create a new Object from type `app`. It is the same as a static constructor, only that it is run every time you create an instance, not only once.

The instance initializer runs **before** the constructor.

For detailed information see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

> Normally, you would put code to initialize an instance variable in a
>   constructor. There are two alternatives to using a constructor to
>   initialize instance variables: initializer blocks and final methods.
>   Initializer blocks for instance variables look just like static
>   initializer blocks, but without the static keyword,